# Purely fictional message

Tags: terminology

At the start of some games it says say that:

"Anything portrayed in this game is purely fictional and any similarities are completely coincidental"

Does that mean every single element of the game?

Example: This message is in MGSTPP

Does that mean all weapons and areas ect... are created from imagination like names of weapons and the look of areas?

Comment: Why was there a downvote out of curiosity

Comment: Your chance of getting a reasoning for your downvote isn't likely to happen. Many people will downvote a question a if they feel it isn't directly related to gaming or shows no research. My money is that they felt that this doesn't count as a gaming question and hence came the downvote.

Comment: @PaulWilliams read what the terminology tag stands for

Comment: I'm not saying that it's right. I'm just telling you why someone downvoted you. (I didn't.) Additionally, the terminology that you mentioned isn't gaming-specific. This warning message appears on everything from episodes of Law and Order to life based movies.

Comment: It says, "For questions that ask what a gaming-specific term means."  This isn't a gaming-specific term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as the [All persons fictitious disclaimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_persons_fictitious_disclaimer), and can be found in many forms of media (not just video games).

Such a disclaimer does not necessarily mean that *anything* in the game is coincidental, let alone *everything*.  On the contrary, an author is more likely to make the disclaimer if a story is inspired by real people or events.

Traditionally, the disclaimer has simply been used as a protection against libel and slander litigation.